# Logitech Nano wireless mouse disconnects on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wireless, usb, mouse

I've read the answers to many similar questions; none appear to nail down a lasting successful result. PC is HP ProBook 6470b (using built-in keyboard). Wired USB mouse works fine, wireless USB mouse in question has 2 batteries pushing 1.75V each.

So. I plug the receiver into the USB 3.0 port, and the mouse works perfectly. Full speed, immediate response. DMESG says:
new full-speed USB device number xxx using xhci_hcd.

Over the next minute or so, response speed gets slower and the mouse pointer lags. Within two minutes, the pointer freezes.

DMESG says:

Device not responding to setup address.

Then red messages saying:

device not accepting address xxx, error -71

unable to enumerate USB device

If I unplug the receiver, wait a few minutes and reconnect, we start again at the top.

A permanent solution would be nice.

Thank you,

John M.

Comment: The permanent solution is to replace the mouse. OS doesn't do anything with it. It acts like a wired mouse to the OS.

Comment: Don't think there's anything wrong with the mouse.  Works perfectly on Windows.  And I just found that reconnecting it (as described above), then moving it continuously for a few minutes seems to keep it alive long after I leave it alone.  And there's a new line in DMESG:  "interrupt took too long (3928 > 3916), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50750".  Any idea what's happening there?